# Error when updating Pending Contribution

Tags: civicontribute

After searching pending contributions and ticking some of them, I select Action > Update Pending Contribution Status > Completed > Update.

I get the following error : "Sorry, we cannot provide this at the moment ; expected one PriceSet but found 19" ... which is rather amazing, since :
- I have only 4 PriceSets defined in my Civi;
- The Contribution Page uses no PriceSet.

However, I don't have any error when I select "Update multiple Contributions" instead of "Update Pending Contribution Status"

(Currently running Civi 4.7.16 / Drupal 7.54)

Comment: I've seen this error message in a different context and I believe it arises when you have a site that has been upgraded from earlier versions, pre-pricesets. In that case, CiviCRM may have converted earlier contribution pages that did not use price sets into hidden price sets, which can cause issues. Can you look in your civicrm_price_set and see if there's anything in there with is_active = 0?

Comment: Thank you Alan for your suggestion, but my installation is very recent : In fact, I have 19 pricesets defined in the civicrm_price_set table (a lot for tests), all of them have is-active = 1 ; but now, I wonder why I have only 5 which are displayed when I ask (menu) Contribution > Pricesets Management.

Comment: There are some priceset mysteries that I haven't delved into, but what you say re-enforces my suspicions about the cause of your error. I've posted details below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the same underlying error reported here:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20297

Specifically, contributions containing line items without a matching priceset can cause problems (because CiviCRM tries to match them up with priceset items and can generate errors when it does that badly).

It seems likely this error can be fixed using the patch provided for that issue, here:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10012

Here's a short cut url to to a patch ready version of that pull request:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10012.diff

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alan, for your answer, which makes sense. I am not very fond of patches, which have to be re-done every Civi update. So, for the time being, I will implement an alternative solution : starting from an Event Report, Consult each Participant, then Modify to update his Participant Status and record his check payment.

Comment: In general, yes, patches are a pain to have to keep current, etc. But that patch is actually now in CiviCRM core and will go out with the next release.